# How to export CKeditor with Features

Tags: wysiwyg, features

I am using [CKeditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) and I would like to be able to export my configuration with [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features).

I find that I am able to put all my CKeditor profiles into a Features module. All the settings are stored in the Features module, but the Profiles don't save the settings of which text format the profile is applied to.

This means that when I enable the features module on a new site, I have to reassign the profiles to the text formats.

How can I overcome this?

I have tried using the dev version of CK editor and strong arm as well.

Note: I am talking about the standalone Drupal CKeditor module and not the one that requires the WYSIWYG module to be installed. I am using this module because it is compatible with the [Drupal Edit project](https://drupal.org/project/edit).

Comment: did you try features together with strongarm?

Comment: @Serpiente, Yes I am using Strong arm. Is there anything special I have to do?

Comment: @big_smile, did you figure this out? I'm currently stuck on this too.

Comment: @Randell No... :/

Comment: It seems to be working for me(ckeditor-7.x-1.14, uuid_features-7.x-1.0-alpha3+15-dev, features-7.x-2.0),however. It is importing FILE BROWSER SETTINGS

Comment: I looked into the features.ckeditor_profile.inc and its no there,so I guess FILE BROWSER SETTINGS is not exporting